# Python: why aren't variables updating?

Tags: python, variables, integer

A python program that I'm debugging has the following code (including `print` statements for debugging):

```
print "BEFORE..."
print "oup[\"0\"] = " + str(oup["0"])
print "oup[\"2008\"] = " + str(oup["2008"])
print "oup[\"2009\"] = " + str(oup["2009"])

oup0 = oup["0"]
oup2008 = oup["2008"]
oup2009 = oup["2009"]
ouptotal = oup2008 + oup2009
print "ouptotal = " + str(ouptotal)

if ouptotal > 0:
    oup["2008"] = oup2008 + oup0 * (oup2008 / ouptotal)
    oup["2009"] = oup2009 + oup0 * (oup2009 / ouptotal)

print "AFTER..."
print "oup[\"0\"] = " + str(oup["0"])
print "oup[\"2008\"] = " + str(oup["2008"])
print "oup[\"2009\"] = " + str(oup["2009"])
```

Up until that point, the variables update correctly.  When I run that code, I get the following on the screen:

```
BEFORE...                                                                       
oup["0"] = 22032                                                                
oup["2008"] = 541                                                               
oup["2009"] = 15223                                                             
ouptotal = 15764                                                                
AFTER...                                                                        
oup["0"] = 22032                                                                
oup["2008"] = 541                                                               
oup["2009"] = 15223
```

Why aren't oup["2008"] and oup["2009"] updating?

(Python version is 2.6.2 on a "Jaunty" Ubuntu machine.)

Comment: From the point of view of someone who *intends* to learn Python, one day, is `oup[2008]` the same as `oup["2008"]` ?

Comment: No. int indexes and str indexes are distinct.

Comment: I removed the printed "oup[2008]", because it might be confusing.

Comment: I thought so. The lists oup["2008"] and oup["2009"] are the *only* ones with str indexes. Ah! I notice the question has been edited.

Comment: Errr... oup["0"] has str index, too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the values are integers, then `(oup2008 / ouptotal)` will be zero, so they will be updated to their own value + 0, hence no change.

Convert them to floats for the calculation, then back if required, and it should work as expected.

Example:

```
oup["2008"] = oup2008 + int(oup0 * (float(oup2008) / ouptotal))
```

Answer (score 3):

Integer division results in integer results. either use `float()` on one of the division terms or add `from __future__ import division` at the top.

Answer (score 1):

They are, you're just updating them with the same value. In Python 2.6, `/` is still an integer division operator([reference](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations)), so dividing `(oup2008 / ouptotal)` is dividing a number by a bigger number, which always results in zero. If you want the behavior from later versions, were `/` is a floating-point operator, you can get it with a future statement importing `division`.